# Managing dynamic loading of dependent JavaScript files with automatic versioning

Tags: javascript, cache, dynamic-loading

I have written a solution for managing dynamic loading of dependent JavaScript files (or executing JS functions) coupled with automatic versioning to refresh browser cache.

The goal was to be able to specify a single `my.js` file and have all dependent js files dynamically loaded with a filename which has been appended with its timestamp (.htaccess filters out the timestamp).

**My hope is to get feedback on my methodology and code**. Is this a methodology others would find useful?

**UPDATE** - I have posted a fully working version of this concept, updated with suggestions as a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/mseifert9/Javascript-Dynamic-Loading-and-Version-Control)

To accomplish the goal:

1. Within each .js file, I specify the list of dependent files with the associated created class object (ns) so I know when the dependent file has been loaded.

   For example, `my.js` may have the following declarations:

   ```
   var dependants = [
       {file: "custom-dialog.min.js", ns: "CustomDialog"},
       {file: function miscFn1(){doSomethingOnLoad()}, dependencies: [{file: function onload(){}}, {file: "dragdrop.min.js", ns: "DragDrop"}]}
   ]
   sourceFiles.add(dependencies);
   sourceFiles.load();
   ```

   Note: All declarations listed in a .js file are for files `dependent` on this file. Declarations can include `dependencies` which must be loaded or executed first. In this example, the file `dragdrop.min.js` must be loaded and the window's `load` event must have fired before the function `doSomethingOnLoad` is run. But the file `custom-dialog.min.js` will be loaded immediately.
2. Within `include.php`, I load the single file `my.js` (the PHP `version()` function adds the file timestamp for this file).

   ```
   <script src="<?php echo version(STATIC_JS_COMMON, 'js-common/my.js') ?>"></script>
   ```
3. Within `include.php`, I specify the directories to poll on the server. The `doVersionChecking()` function makes an HTTP request to the server which returns all file timestamps for the specified directories (I'm happy to post this code if anyone would find this helpful).

   ```
   <script>
       sourceFiles.doVersionChecking([
           // specify url of directories to read file times for
           $ms.STATIC_JS_COMMON,
           $ms.STATIC_JS_COMMON + "/subdir"
       ]);
   </script>
   ```

   .htaccess code - to remove the timestamp from the filename

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
       #Rules for Versioned Static Files
       RewriteRule ^(js|js-common|css|css-common|img|img-common)/(.+)\.([0-9])+\.(js|css|php|jpg|gif|png)(.*)$ $1/$2.$4$5 [L]
   ```

Below is the JavaScript code. The only code missing is the PHP code for returning the files with their associated timestamps.

Note: all `STATIC_` (PHP) and `$ms.STATIC_` (JS) variables contain URL paths to the files on the server. The server translates the URL paths to absolute paths in order to find the files and read the timestamps.

```
// manage dynamic loading of source files (js, css, img) and js functions
var sourceFiles = {
  queued: [],
  loading: [],
  source: [],
  fileInfo: [],
  versionCheck: [], // array of version check requests
  versionCheckPaths: [], // list of paths checked with version checking
  staticRoot: function() {
    if (typeof $ms.STATIC_TOP_ROOT !== "undefined") {
      return $ms.STATIC_TOP_ROOT;
    } else {
      return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host;
    }
  },
  staticJsCommon: function() {
    if (typeof $ms.STATIC_JS_COMMON !== "undefined") {
      return $ms.STATIC_JS_COMMON;
    } else {
      return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + "/js-common";
    }
  },
  staticImgCommon: function() {
    if (typeof $ms.STATIC_IMG_COMMON !== "undefined") {
      return $ms.STATIC_IMG_COMMON;
    } else {
      return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + "/img-common";
    }
  },
  doVersionChecking: function(path) {
    // set function sourceFiles.versionChecking as a dependency
    // file times will be retrieved from server before any dependent js files
    // each js file will have file time added to the name to mangage file versions
    // .htaccess removes the file version from the file name        
    var dependencies = [
      // all functions must have a unique name - create one on the fly
      {
        file: new Function("return function versionChecking" + sourceFiles.versionCheck.length + "(){$ms.sourceFiles.versionChecking(" + JSON.stringify(path) + ")}")()
      }
    ];
    sourceFiles.add(dependencies);
    sourceFiles.load();
  },
  add: function(source) {
    if (!Array.isArray(source)) {
      source = [source];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      // test if namespace specified and if already exists
      if (sourceFiles.alreadyLoadedNs(source[i].ns)) continue;

      if (typeof source[i].file == "function") {
        var funcName = /function ([^\(]+)?/.exec(source[i].file.toString())[0];
        source[i].baseFile = funcName;
        source[i].loaded = false;
        source[i].type = "function";
        if (funcName == "function onload") {
          if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
            // condition already satisfied
            sourceFiles.onload({
              target: {
                src: sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile
              }
            });
          } else {
            window.addEventListener("load", sourceFiles.load);
          }
        }
      } else {
        var baseFile = source[i].file.substr(source[i].file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        var split = baseFile.split("?");
        baseFile = split[0];
        source[i].baseFile = baseFile
        var ext = baseFile.substr(baseFile.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (ext == "js") {
          source[i].type = "js";
        } else if (ext == "css") {
          source[i].type = "css";
        } else if (ext == "php") {
          if (baseFile.indexOf("css.php") !== -1) {
            source[i].type = "css";
          } else {
            source[i].type = "php";
          }
        } else if (["jpg", "png", "gif"].indexOf(ext) !== -1) {
          source[i].type = "img";
        } else {
          source[i].type = "unknown";
          console.log("Source File unknown type for: " + source[i].file);
        }

        var dir = "";
        if (typeof source[i].dir == "undefined") {
          // default = js-common
          dir = sourceFiles.staticJsCommon();
        } else if (typeof source[i].dir == "js-common") {
          dir = sourceFiles.staticJsCommon();
        } else if (typeof source[i].dir == "css-common") {
          dir = sourceFiles.staticCssCommon();
        } else if (typeof source[i].dir == "img-common") {
          dir = sourceFiles.staticImgCommon();
        }

        var subDir = "";
        if (source[i].file.indexOf("/") !== -1) {
          // full directory explicitly set
        } else if (typeof source[i].subDir !== "undefined") {
          // relative to specified or default subDir
          subDir = "/" + source[i].subDir;
        }
        source[i].file = dir + subDir + "/" + source[i].file;
        source[i].loaded = false;
      }
      // test if file already added to load queue
      if (sourceFiles.queued.indexOf(source[i].baseFile) !== -1) continue;

      if (source[i].dependencies) {
        for (var j = 0; j < source[i].dependencies.length; j++) {
          // queue the dependencies
          sourceFiles.add(source[i].dependencies[j]);
        }
      } else {
        source[i].dependencies = [];
      }
      // add to queue to be loaded
      // flag file is queued for loading
      sourceFiles.queued.push(source[i].baseFile);

      sourceFiles.source.push(source[i]);
    }
  },
  load: function() {
    var versionCheckLength = sourceFiles.versionCheck.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceFiles.versionCheck.length; i++) {
      if (sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].timeStamp > 0 && !sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].complete) {
        // if the response from the server not yet received - set interval to wait for it
        if (typeof sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].interval !== "undefined") {
          // interval already running
          return;
        }
        sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].complete || Date.now() - sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].timeStamp >= sourceFiles.versionCheckingTimeout) {
            clearInterval(sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].interval);
            if (!sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].complete) {
              console.log("Timeout checking js version (" + i + ")");
            }
            sourceFiles.versionCheck[i].complete = true;
            sourceFiles.load();
          }
        }, 10);
        return;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceFiles.source.length; i++) {
      if (versionCheckLength !== sourceFiles.versionCheck.length) {
        // if version checking has been added - start over
        sourceFiles.load();
        return;
      }
      // remove dependencies that are already loaded
      sourceFiles.removeDependencies(sourceFiles.source[i]);
      // load all files with no dependencies
      if (sourceFiles.source[i].dependencies.length == 0) {
        if (sourceFiles.source[i].loaded) {
          // file already loaded
          continue;
          //} else if (sourceFiles.loading.indexOf(sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile) !== -1){
          // files already added to load queue
          //continue;
        } else if (typeof sourceFiles.source[i].file == "function") {
          // function - execute the function
          var funcName = /function ([^\(]+)?/.exec(sourceFiles.source[i].file.toString())[0];
          if (funcName == "function onload") {
            // special function that has no body
            var result = (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive");
          } else {
            //v("executing " + sourceFiles.source[i].file.toString());
            var result = sourceFiles.source[i].file();
          }
          if (result !== false) {
            sourceFiles.source[i].loaded = true;
            sourceFiles.onLoad({
              target: {
                src: sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile
              }
            });
          }
          continue;
        }
        // test if namespace specified and if already exists
        if (sourceFiles.alreadyLoadedNs(sourceFiles.source[i].ns)) continue;
        if (sourceFiles.loading.indexOf(sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile) !== -1) continue;

        var version = "";
        if (sourceFiles.fileInfo.find(function(fileInfo) {
            if (fileInfo.baseFile == sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile) {
              version = '.' + fileInfo.time + '.';
              return true;
            }
          })) {
          // keep baseFile the same - change the full filename with version
          // replaces my.file.js with my.file.123456.js where 123456 is the file timestamp
          sourceFiles.source[i].file = sourceFiles.source[i].file.replace(/\.(?!.*?\.)/, version);
        }
        // flag loading file
        sourceFiles.loading.push(sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile);

        // file - load the source file
        loadSourceFile(sourceFiles.source[i].file, sourceFiles.source[i].type, sourceFiles.onLoad)
      }
    }
  },
  alreadyLoadedNs: function(ns) {
    // test if namespace specified and if already exists
    if (typeof ns == "undefined") return false;
    var exists = true;
    var path = ns.split(".");
    for (var j = 0; j < path.length; j++) {
      if (typeof $msRoot[path[j]] == "undefined") {
        // namespace not yet created
        return false;
      }
    }
    // namespace exists
    return true;
  },
  onLoad: function(e) {
    // flag file as loaded
    var baseFile = e.target.src.substr(e.target.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var split = baseFile.split("?");
    baseFile = split[0];
    // remove the version timestamp from the filename
    baseFile = baseFile.replace(/(.+)\.([0-9])+\.(js|css|php|jpg|gif|png)$/, "$1.$3");
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceFiles.source.length; i++) {
      if (sourceFiles.source[i].baseFile == baseFile) {
        sourceFiles.source[i].loaded = true;
        if (sourceFiles.source[i].onLoad) {
          // custom onLoad
          sourceFiles.source[i].onLoad();
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    sourceFiles.load();
  },
  removeDependencies: function(source) {
    if (!source.loaded) {
      for (var j = source.dependencies.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        // test if namespace specified and if already exists
        if (typeof source.dependencies[j].ns !== "undefined" && sourceFiles.alreadyLoadedNs(source.dependencies[j].ns)) {
          // loaded - remove the dependencey
          source.dependencies.splice(j, 1);
          continue;
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < sourceFiles.source.length; k++) {
          var source2 = sourceFiles.source[k];
          if (source2.baseFile == source.dependencies[j].baseFile) {
            // found the dependency
            if (source2.loaded) {
              // loaded - remove the dependencey
              source.dependencies.splice(j, 1);
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  versionChecking: function(path) {
    // poll server for file times for specified directories
    if (!Array.isArray(path)) {
      path = [path];
    }
    sourceFiles.versionCheck.push({});
    var versionCheck = sourceFiles.versionCheck[sourceFiles.versionCheck.length - 1]
    versionCheck.id = sourceFiles.versionCheck.length;
    versionCheck.timeStamp = Date.now();
    versionCheck.complete = false
    versionCheck.path = path;
    var url = $ms.LINK_SITE_ROOT + "/moddate.php";
    var data = {
      path: path
    };
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "id=moddate-js&url=" + url + "&otherData=" + data;
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        //alert(http.responseText);
        var response = http.responseText;
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        var error = false;
        if (typeof data !== "object" || !data.status) {
          console.log("Invalid version checking response: " + response);
          error = true;
        } else if (data.status.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") !== -1) {
          console.log(data.status);
          error = true;
        } else if (data.status.toLowerCase().indexOf("success") == -1) {
          console.log("Unknown response (missing success): " + response);
          error = true;
        }
        if (!error) {
          console.log("Version information loaded");
          sourceFiles.fileInfo = sourceFiles.fileInfo.concat(data.result);
        }
        // if there was an error, will load files without version info
        versionCheck.complete = true;
        sourceFiles.load();
      }
    }
    http.send(params);
  }
}

// dynamically load a js or css file
function loadSourceFile(filename, filetype, onloadFn) {
  if (typeof filetype == "undefined") {
    filetype = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
  }
  if (filetype == "js") {
    // load js file
    var item = document.createElement('script');
    item.type = "text/javascript";
    item.src = filename;
  } else if (filetype == "css") {
    //load CSS file
    var item = document.createElement("link");
    item.rel = "stylesheet";
    item.type = "text/css";
    item.href = filename;
  } else if (filetype == "img") {
    // preloading images
    var item = document.createElement("img");
    item.style.display = "none";
    item.src = filename;
  }
  if (typeof onloadFn !== "undefined") {
    item.onload = onloadFn;
    //item.onreadystatechange = runFn;
  }
  if (typeof item != "undefined") {
    if (filetype == "img") {
      document.body.appendChild(item);
    } else {
      document.head.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: `RewriteRule ^(js|js-common|css|css-common|img|img-common)` could be `RewriteRule ^(js|css|img)(-common)?`

Comment: Also, this: `file: function miscFn1(){doSomethingOnLoad()}` could be `file: doSomethingOnLoad`. (unless you really need to alias `doSomethingOnLoad` as `miscFn1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did not check or run the whole code, but I do see lots of code repetition that you should avoid. 
For example, returning a windows.location should use a help function.

So these kind of lines

```
return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + "/js-common";
```

could be:

```
return buildURL("/js-common")
```

It's not only about the size of the code, it is mainly for other reasons, like, reusability, readability, maintainability, etc. Some times we prefer more size if it comes with one or more of these pros.

*UPDATE*

Checking once more your code, there is a bunch of repeted code you should turn into methods.
For instance, this whole part

```
var dir = "";
if (typeof source[i].dir == "undefined") {
    // default = js-common
    dir = sourceFiles.staticJsCommon();
} else if (typeof source[i].dir == "js-common") {
    dir = sourceFiles.staticJsCommon();
} else if (typeof source[i].dir == "css-common") {
    dir = sourceFiles.staticCssCommon();
} else if (typeof source[i].dir == "img-common") {
    dir = sourceFiles.staticImgCommon();
}
```

should become one method with one param

```
var dir = sourceFiles.handleFileDir(source[i].dir)
```

and all the methods below

```
staticRoot : function () {
    if (typeof $ms.STATIC_TOP_ROOT !== "undefined") {
        return $ms.STATIC_TOP_ROOT;
    } else {
        return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host;
    }
},
staticJsCommon : function () {
    if (typeof $ms.STATIC_JS_COMMON !== "undefined") {
        return $ms.STATIC_JS_COMMON;
    } else {
        return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + "/js-common";
    }
},
staticImgCommon : function () {
    if (typeof $ms.STATIC_IMG_COMMON !== "undefined") {
        return $ms.STATIC_IMG_COMMON;
    } else {
        return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + "/img-common";
    }
}
```

are really only one method. Could be something like

```
handleFileDir : function (pathPart) {
    // decide on type ref and define the var
    var typeToCheck = function (_path) {
        if (_path.indexOf("js") > -1) return "STATIC_JS_COMMON";
        if (_path.indexOf("css") > -1) return "STATIC_CSS_COMMON";
        if (_path.indexOf("img") > -1) return "STATIC_IMG_COMMON";
        return "STATIC_TOP_ROOT";       
    }(pathPart);

    if (typeof $ms[typeToCheck] !== "undefined") {
        return $ms[typeToCheck];
    } else {
        return window.location.origin ? window.location.origin + '/' : window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + pathPart;
    }
}
```

Always be suspicious of code smell when parts of your code look alike so much...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With one liners I tend to resist creating another function. But I can do better with the other more significant cases.

Comment: It's not only about the size, it is mainly for other reasons, like, reusability, readability, maintainability, etc